# How to take key input from user?

Tags: python

How to take key input in `key = b'8_bit_key_from_user'`?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
from secrets import token_bytes
input_key = input()
key  = b''+input_key
```

Output:

```
File "c:\Users\PAssWORD\Music\des.py", line 16, in <module>
key  = b''+input_key
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

Comment: I dont think b'' is valid syntax, maybe "b\'\' " was what you were looking for?

Comment: @chess_lover_6 `b''` is actually valid syntax.

Comment: Huh, guess I learned something new today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `key = b'' + input_key` try `key = bytes(input_key, 'utf-8')`. In the former you're trying to concatenate an empty byte variable to a string variable, hence the error.